# Angular access json element name containing multiple words

Tags: json, angularjs

I need to call a service with returns a JSON array. But the array element name can contains several words.

example

```
 {"commerciele productnaam":"my product","looptijd in jaren":"0", etc... }
```

I am writing an angular controller which fetches the data, but I am unable to get the value of "commerciele productnaam".

```
<div ng-controller="PriceController as pc" ng-init="pc.getPrices()">
    <h1>Price from Pricing Service</h1>
    {{ pc.prices.msg.HOW TO ACCESS COMMERCIELE PRODUCTNAAM }} 

    <br/>
    <br/>
    MSG == {{ pc.prices.msg }} 
</div>
```

Is it possible to fetch the value via the variable name anyhow ?

Comment: use `[]` `pc.prices.msg['HOW TO ACCESS COMMERCIELE PRODUCTNAAM']` notation that takes the property name string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets instead:

```
<div ng-controller="PriceController as pc" ng-init="pc.getPrices()">
    <h1>Price from Pricing Service</h1>
    {{ pc.prices.msg['commerciele productnaam'] }} 

    <br/>
    <br/>
    MSG == {{ pc.prices.msg }} 
</div>
```

The bracket operator can be used instead of the dot operator to get object properties and you can use any string while the dot operator is more limited: no whitespaces, etc.